# How to change color of an image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, images

When I open an image in Photoshop, I can easily change the color by double clicking on the layer and adding color overlay.

How can I do the same in Illustrator? It doesn't need to be with Color overlay (since I now that there isn't color overlay in Illustrator)
Just how do I change the color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a bit futile to think of illustrator in the same way as Photoshop. They work differently. The concept of layers in illustrator, is a totally different way of looking at the world.

Anyway do this:

1. Select the layer. Use the round thing next to the layer name, this selects the layer object. Selecting name activates layer, that is a different thing.

   [image: Select layer]

   **Image 1**: Select the layer object (round box *next*  to name)
2. In the Appearances panel click add new fill (and possibly stroke or expand it with a pathfinder effect)

   [image]

   **Image 2**: Add new fill
3. Make the fill the color you want.

#### NOTE:

Odds are you just want to select all objects and apply a color. Instead of bothering with arcane appearance settings that hardly anybody understands.

Comment: Fill will not consider opacity like color overlay in Photoshop.

Comment: @kelin not the same way but same effect can be achieved by manipulating the appearance stack.

Comment: do you know, how?

Comment: Yes, but its a bit messy.